# Remove disable attribute when textareas have value

Tags: jquery

I have a form with a few textareas and selectors and the submit button which is disabled be default. I need to remove "disabled" attribute when each textarea has has at least something in them.

Tried this, but it does not seem to work:

```
$("#mySubmit").parent().find("textarea").change(function(){
    if ($(this).val() != "") {
        $("#mySubmit").removeAttr("disabled");
    } else {
        $("#mySubmit").attr("disabled");
    }   
});
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You should make that validation on the `form submit`, not on change of the `textarea`.

Comment: @gdoron Why on submit? Why not fix the issue while filling out the form?

Comment: This is how it's implemented in in most cases, especially in the Validaion plugin

Comment: I know, but the advent of AJAX lets us improve overall user experience. And actually the validation plugin below does it instantly, possibly on .keyup()

Comment: Do you know what `AJAX` is? it's has nothing to do with this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
var $textarea = $("#mySubmit").parent().find("textarea");
var disable = ($("#mySubmit").parent().find("textarea").filter(function(){
    return $.trim($(this).val()) == "";
}).length == $textarea.length);  
$("#mySubmit").prop("disabled", disable);
```

`.prop()` reference: http://api.jquery.com/prop/ jQuery Ver 1.6+

If you are using older version then use `attr`/`removeAttr` instead of `prop`.

```
if(disable){
    $("#mySubmit").removeAttr("disabled");
}
else{
    $("#mySubmit").attr("disabled", true);
}
```

Comment: Yes, I have to work with v.1.4. I need to be able to add/remove attribute as user works on the textareas and when ALL of them are not empty. For example if he/she empties one of them, the button needs to become disabled again... Shall i put your code inside $("#mySubmit").parent().find("textarea").change(function(){
}); let me try that.

Comment: This works great, but it enables a button even if one of the textareas is not empty. I need this to happen when all of them are.

Comment: I thought that is what you wanted. Anyways I have changed the condition as per your need. Take a look at my edit.

Comment: Brilliant. I just changed to }).length == 0);  and it worked great! Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#mySubmit").attr("disabled",'disabled');
```

Comment: and use (!$(this).val()) instead of  ($(this).val() != "")

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that the selector `$("#mySubmit").parent().find("textarea")` is working? If you a debugger like firebug or the built in debugger in chrome, you can test it and see if you get something. Also I assume you only want to enable the submit if all textarea have something.

Try replacing it with

```
$("textarea").change(function(){

var emptyTextarea = false
$("textarea").each(function(){
    if($(this).val()=="")
    {
        emtpyTextarea = true;
    }
});

if(!emptyTextarea)
{
    $("#mySubmit").removeAttr("disabled");
}
});
```

I'd also recommend using the jquery validate plugin, as it handles stuff like this beautifully:
http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($(this).val() != "") {
    $("#mySubmit").attr("disabled", "");
} else {
    $("#mySubmit").attr("disabled", "disabled");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($('textarea:empty').length == 0) {
  $('#submitButton').removeAttr('disabled');
}
```